# how to center text of a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, center-align

My question is self explanatory: how to center the text of a JSpinner? the methode setHorizontalAligment is not there. I also tried setAlignmentX, still nothing... Any help would be appreciated c:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`JSpinner` is a container of other components, one of which is a the editor.

```
JSpinner spinner = ...;
JComponent editor = spinner.getEditor();
```

But that doesn't help us, as `setHorizontalAligment` isn't a method of `JComponent`.

You can then inspect the `editor` type of component it is...

```
if (editor instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor) {
```

If it's a `JSpinner.DefaultEditor`, you can cast it and use `setHorizontalAlignment`...

```
JSpinner.DefaultEditor spinnerEditor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor)editor;
spinnerEditor.getTextField().setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
```

Potentionally you may also need to check for `JTextField` as well, but if you're using the default editor models, it would normally return `JSpinner.DefaultEditor`

Comment: sadly, the JSpinner doesn't seem to have an instance of JTextField... But thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Thanks you very much! This worked just fine! I hated the text to be on the right somehow. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @user3342795 Yeah, love spinners :P

Comment: I'd like to add a couple of things to this answer: 1) The reason for this behavior is that [apparently](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-spinners-in-matlab-gui#comment-367963) the `JSpinner` component creates its internal `TextField` using the parent control’s property values when it is first rendered, and then ignores changes to the parent property values. 2) If working with JComponents in MATLAB, it is sufficient to call e.g. `jSpinner.getEditor.getTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.LEFT);` to get the desired effect.

Comment: `jSpinner.getEditor.getTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.L‌​EFT);` ... which is basically what the answer says